# Problem in setting session attribute in jsp function

Tags: jsp, session

I am trying to set session attribute in a jsp function. 
The function reads cell data from a table row and stores it in a variable array.
Could you suggest how can I set the array_variable to the session ?
My code is as below -

function sendData(recordToSend)
{
    var sessionData = new Array();

```
var table = document.getElementById("tblReport");

var rowNum = parseInt(recordToSend);

var cells=table.rows[rowNum].cells;

for(var c=1;c<cells.length;c++)
{
    sessionData[c-1] = cells[c].innerText;
}

<%
session.setAttribute("tableData",sessionData);// problem is here 
%>
```

}

Thanks for upcoming suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java/JSP and JavaScript do not run in sync as you'd expect from the coding. Java/JSP runs at the webserver upon a HTTP request and produces HTML/CSS/JS code which get sent back to webbrowser as a HTTP response. All the webbrowser retrieves is a bunch of HTML/CSS/JS code without any single line of Java/JSP code.

To the point, you need to let your JS (or a HTML form) send a HTTP request with the desired request parameters to the webserver and hook some Java (Servlet) code on the request URL so that it can set the session attribute based on the request parameters. You could let JavaScript fill hidden input values of a form and submit it, or send an Ajax request.